# Binding on a List<UserControl>

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, user-controls, pixelsense

I got some binding issues...

Shapes is a list of customized UserControls, for example one of those UserControl can be an Ellipse with some specific properties. My goal is to loop on this list and show all the UserControls (it can be an Ellipse, or a Rectangle...) I just want to show the UserControl like if I would just prompt his XAML Content.

Here is my grid, i just don't know what to put in the DataTemplate, i tried some different things but nothing worked actually, hope some can help me :)

```
<Grid>
    <s:ScatterView ItemsSource="{Binding Shapes}">
        <s:ScatterView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="s:ScatterViewItem">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"></Setter>
            </Style>
            </s:ScatterView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <s:ScatterView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <class:Shape ShapeItem="{Binding}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </s:ScatterView.ItemTemplate>
    </s:ScatterView>
</Grid>
```

Comment: if your ShapeItem is UserControl. have you tried to bind that with `Content` Property of `ContentControl`?

Comment: Actually i just did : <class:Shape Content="{Binding}" /> and it works well... (Shape is a custom UserControl). Thanks for your answer, i was rly stupid on this one :(

Answer (score 0):

as mention in comment.if your ShapeItem is UserControl try to bind that with Content Property.